# Cannot achieve maximum CPU frequency with Intel_Pstate Driver - RHEL 7.7

Tags: rhel, cpu, cpu-frequency

I'm struggling with intel_pstate performance governor not running at max CPU speed.  I have a 2.2ghz system, and it needs to be running at full speed for valid reasons.

```
# grep -E '^model name|^cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1393.933
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1344.519
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1379.833
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1398.901
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1352.709
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1395.007
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1356.738
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1350.292
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1349.890
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1354.589
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1554.260
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1513.439
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1500.952
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1466.442
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1515.856
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1552.917
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1495.178
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1476.245
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1518.945
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 1493.566
```

cpupower shows **performance** governor, but that the frequency isn't adjusting:

```
# cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 2.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.00 GHz and 2.20 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 1.35 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
```

tuned-adm list shows the throughput-performance governor selected:

```
# tuned-adm list
Available profiles:
- balanced                    - General non-specialized tuned profile
- desktop                     - Optimize for the desktop use-case
- hpc-compute                 - Optimize for HPC compute workloads
- latency-performance         - Optimize for deterministic performance at the cost of increased power consumption
- network-latency             - Optimize for deterministic performance at the cost of increased power consumption, focused on low latency network performance
- network-throughput          - Optimize for streaming network throughput, generally only necessary on older CPUs or 40G+ networks
- powersave                   - Optimize for low power consumption
- throughput-performance      - Broadly applicable tuning that provides excellent performance across a variety of common server workloads
- virtual-guest               - Optimize for running inside a virtual guest
- virtual-host                - Optimize for running KVM guests
Current active profile: throughput-performance
```

cpufreq file system shows the minimum is not being adjusted and that "setspeed" isn't supported:

```
grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/affected_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:1439721
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:2200000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:1200000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_transition_latency:4294967295
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/related_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:1439721
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:2200000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:2000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed:<unsupported>
```

I've been able to disable intel_pstate, which results in maximum CPU frequency on reboot, but I was hoping to tune the system down to 1.9 GHz for a test.  When I disable intel_pstate, acpi scaling is not available and cpupower cannot do anything.

Pertinent Information:

- OS Version: RHEL 7.7
- Kernel: 3.10.0-1062.9.1.rt56.1033.el7.x86_64 #1
  SMP PREEMPT RT Mon Dec 2 12:20:53 EST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
  GNU/Linux
- cpufreq_ondemand: not available
- thermal throttle: all set to zero in individual cpu* folders
- Dmesg info:

```
# dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn
ACPI: RSDP 00000000000f05b0 00024 (v02 ALASKA)
ACPI: XSDT 00000000799820a0 000C4 (v01 ALASKA   A M I  01072009 AMI  00010013)
ACPI: FACP 00000000799b4ed8 0010C (v05 ALASKA   A M I  01072009 AMI  00010013)
ACPI: DSDT 0000000079982200 32CD7 (v02 ALASKA   A M I  01072009 INTL 20091013)
ACPI: FACS 0000000079e5bf80 00040
ACPI: APIC 00000000799b4fe8 0017C (v03 ALASKA   A M I  01072009 AMI  00010013)
ACPI: FPDT 00000000799b5168 00044 (v01 ALASKA   A M I  01072009 AMI  00010013)
ACPI: FIDT 00000000799b51b0 0009C (v01 ALASKA   A M I  01072009 AMI  00010013)
ACPI: TCPA 00000000799b5250 00032 (v02 ALASKA  NAPAASF 00000000 MSFT 01000013)
ACPI: MCFG 00000000799b5288 0003C (v01 ALASKA    A M I 01072009 MSFT 00000097)
ACPI: UEFI 00000000799b52c8 00042 (v01 ALASKA   A M I  01072009      00000000)
ACPI: HPET 00000000799b5310 00038 (v01 ALASKA   A M I  00000001 INTL 20091013)
ACPI: MSCT 00000000799b5348 00090 (v01 ALASKA   A M I  00000001 INTL 20091013)
ACPI: SLIT 00000000799b53d8 00030 (v01 ALASKA   A M I  00000001 INTL 20091013)
ACPI: SRAT 00000000799b5408 01158 (v03 ALASKA   A M I  00000001 INTL 20091013)
ACPI: WDDT 00000000799b6560 00040 (v01 ALASKA   A M I  00000000 INTL 20091013)
ACPI: SSDT 00000000799b65a0 16FB3 (v02 ALASKA    PmMgt 00000001 INTL 20120913)
ACPI: NITR 00000000799cd558 00071 (v02 ALASKA   A M I  00000001 INTL 20091013)
ACPI: SPCR 00000000799cd5d0 00050 (v01  A M I  APTIO V 01072009 AMI. 0005000B)
ACPI: TPM2 00000000799cd620 00034 (v03        Tpm2Tabl 00000001 AMI  00000000)
ACPI: SSDT 00000000799cd658 02652 (v02 ALASKA SpsNm    00000002 INTL 20120913)
ACPI: SSDT 00000000799cfcb0 00064 (v02 ALASKA SpsNvs   00000002 INTL 20120913)
ACPI: PRAD 00000000799cfd18 00102 (v02 ALASKA   A M I  00000002 INTL 20120913)
ACPI: DMAR 00000000799cfe20 00108 (v01 ALASKA   A M I  00000001 INTL 20091013)
Zone ranges:
  DMA      [mem 0x00001000-0x00ffffff]
  DMA32    [mem 0x01000000-0xffffffff]
  Normal   [mem 0x100000000-0x207fffffff]
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x00001000-0x00098fff]
  node   0: [mem 0x00100000-0x7908efff]
  node   0: [mem 0x100000000-0x107fffffff]
  node   1: [mem 0x1080000000-0x207fffffff]
Built 2 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 33001935
Policy zone: Normal
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: View and update with x86_energy_perf_policy(8)
ACPI: All ACPI Tables successfully acquired
ACPI: Enabled 5 GPEs in block 00 to 3F
KSM thread running on realtime kernel. This may introduce latency spikes...
Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
i8042: No controller found
systemd[1]: [/run/systemd/generator/dev-mapper-vg00\x2dlv_root.device.d/timeout.conf:3] Unknown lvalue 'JobRunningTimeoutSec' in section 'Unit'
mlx5_port_module_event: 3 callbacks suppressed
tsyncpci: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Spectracom TSync Timing Board - version 3.12
Copyright (c) 2013 Spectracom Corporation
TSYNC version of board: tsyncpci0
audit_printk_skb: 156 callbacks suppressed
ibm4765: ibm4765, version 2.1.1, build 8 built at Jan 28 2020 18:24:36 initializing
intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
```

Grub Default:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="crashkernel=auto rd.shell=0 rd.auto=1 audit=1 acpi_pad.disable=1 nmi_watchdog=1 boot=/dev/sda2 console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=ttyS1 text"
```

Comment: What OS and version are you running? What's your kernel version? Do you have the `cpufreq_ondemand` module? Can you load it? Can you post the output of `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` ?

Comment: Also check if you have a `thermal_throttle` directory under `/sys/devices/system/cpu`

Comment: Updated question with the details you requested.  No ondemand, no thermal_throttle directory at cpu level (exists at cpuX level, all files set to 0) and dmesg pasted.

Comment: From your logs: `intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor`.

The `thermal_throttle` directory must exist for you. I've no idea why it doesn't. Please blacklist the intel_pstate module and try using the classic ACPI driver.

Comment: how would I go about doing that? I can disable intel_pstate by adding intel_pstate=disable to the boot line.  Is acpi_pad the classic driver?

Comment: I figured it out. We had acpi_pad.disable=1 on our boot line. I removed that and disabled intel_pstate.  I'm able to step according to acpi settings, which is great, but it doesn't help me understand why intel_pstate wasn't behaving correctly.

Comment: `intel_pstate`  used to be an experimental driver back in the day and considering you're running RHEL 7.7 it's very much so.